# Using MOLUSCE plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, molusce

I am trying to explore MOLUSCE ver 3.0.4 in QGIS Dufour. I am trying to simulate the land use change using this tool. I have following querries:

1. It asks for Initial and final year at the first step. Where to enter the exact year for which user is interested for prediction?
2. It gives output file of simulation. For which year this simulation is? Since we already have given Initial and Final year.

Answer (score 4):

Simulation is for the (final_year - start_year1) + final_year, or in other words your first and final year both define time span and your forecast is for final year + this timespan.

Keep in mind, that it doesn't really matter if you assign particular years or not, think in periods.

Comment: This helps! I could also see a PDF file of MOLUSCE version 2.0j, where is allows the user to enter exact year. Is this version available for download? I guess its experimental version.

Comment: 2.0 is too old, don't recommend to use it. Setting year is really just for visual purposes, result won't change if you enter different year.